# Is there a way to force an AssemblyLoadContext to unload?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, .net-assembly, appdomain

I am working on a big ASP.Net 5 web application, and I would like to implement a self-update feature. Since the program can be deployed on many different platform and different ways (e.g. a Windows Service, a systemd service on linux, Docker container, etc...), the only viable way of implementing a self update mechanism is to write a host process that can load and unload the main program DLL and its dependencies. Unloading is important because the host program (updater) must be able to overwrite the server's DLL files while it's running.

Here's what I've done so far: I have changed the output type of the main web application to Library, and I've made a small loader program that loads this DLL and its dependencies into an `HostAssemblyLoadContext`, then invokes the original `Main()` method. The server application is programmed to shut down gracefully a few seconds after it starts up, so the `CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run()` and the `Main()` method can return. After this, I try to call `HostAssemblyLoadContext.Unload()`, but for some reason, the load context refuses to actually unload.

Here's my HostAssemblyLoadContext implementation:

```cs
public class HostAssemblyLoadContext : AssemblyLoadContext
{
    private readonly AssemblyDependencyResolver _resolver;

    public HostAssemblyLoadContext(string pluginPath) : base(isCollectible: true)
    {
        _resolver = new AssemblyDependencyResolver(pluginPath);
    }

    protected override Assembly? Load(AssemblyName name)
    {
        string? assemblyPath = _resolver.ResolveAssemblyToPath(name);
        if (assemblyPath != null)
            return LoadFromAssemblyPath(assemblyPath);

        string filePath = $"{name.FullName.Split(',')[0]}.dll";
        if(File.Exists(filePath))
            return Assembly.LoadFrom(filePath);

        return null;
    }
}
```

My loader code:

```cs
[MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.NoInlining)]
private static void ExecuteMainMethod(string[] args, string assemblyFileName, out WeakReference contextReference, out HostAssemblyLoadContext loadContext)
{
    loadContext = new HostAssemblyLoadContext(new DirectoryInfo(".").FullName);
    contextReference = new WeakReference(loadContext);

    var assembly = loadContext.LoadFromAssemblyPath(assemblyFileName);
    var mainMethod = FindMainMethod(assembly)!;

    try
    {
        mainMethod.Invoke(null, new object?[] {args});
    }
    catch
    {
        // ignore
    }
}

[MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.NoInlining)]
private static void Unload(WeakReference weakReference, ref HostAssemblyLoadContext loadContext)
{
    loadContext.Unload(); 
    loadContext = null;

    for (int i = 0; weakReference.IsAlive && i < 100; i++)
    {
        GC.Collect();
        GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
    }

    Console.WriteLine($"is alive: {weakReference.IsAlive}");
}

public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    ExecuteMainMethod(args, new FileInfo("FirestormSW.SmartGrade.dll").FullName, out var weakReference, out var loadContext);
    Unload(weakReference, ref loadContext);
        
    Console.Out.WriteLine("Press ENTER to exit");
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

And the main method of the actual ASP server:

```cs
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.Out.WriteLine("Starting Server...");
    CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
    Console.Out.WriteLine("Server stopped.");
}
```

Note that if I replace the contents of this Main method with a simple `Thread.Sleep(1000)`, the context does unload successfully.

When I run this program, and wait for the server to shut itself down, this is what I see on the console:

```
Starting Server...
Shutting down...
is alive: True
```

This means that the server's main method has returned, but something is still keeping the load context alive. I have looked at the thread count (`Process.GetCurrentProcess().Threads.Count`) before and after the server is started/stopped, and the number jumps from 8 up to 27. This makes me assume that the context is being kept alive by some threads that are created by the ASP.Net application, but I'm not sure. And if that's the case, I don't know how to find out which threads are responsible, and even if I could, I'm not sure if it's possible to abort them.

Comment: Hi @Lázár Zsolt, please refer to this official document:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/assembly/unloadability.

Comment: @Rena I've spent hours browsing that document, including the part about WinDbg debugging, but my application still has three strong handles that are keeping it alive (one form Newtonsoft.Json, one from EF Core, can't remember what the third is). I'm gonna have to see if I can use some reflection magic to "fix" these, but for the most part, I've given up on this feature.

Comment: I have the same issue. 

Is there any solution that the unload "release" the assembly? Or is it possible any other way to change the plugin.dll during runtime?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Unbelievable, no clear solution for a simple thing you could do with AppDomain. I miss dot net framework.